# virtualenv not importing project settings

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

Good day, facing a weird issue for 3 days now, and I did not find any solution so far. I read so many answers, but still they did not help me so far. This is the traceback I'm receiving for my project:

```
(empire243)drcongo@congodevpro:~$ django-admin check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/drcongo/empireInstances/empireApp/dev_settings.py", line 1, in <module>
    from empireMarket.settings import *
ImportError: No module named 'empireMarket'
(empire243)drcongo@congodevpro:~$
```

- When I do: echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, it returns my dev_settings.py which is correct.
- When I do add2virtualenv there's the path to my instance settings directory.
- When I do which django-admin or which django-admin.py in the virtualenv it returns :  /home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/bin/django-admin and /home/drcongo/.virtualenvs/empire243/bin/django-admin.py

and this is my dev_settings:

dev_settings.py

```
from empireMarket.settings import *


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os.path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'sfsdvvsdfwerwrff'


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INTERNAL_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    '10.0.0.2',
]

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Django Debug Toolbar
INSTALLED_APPS = list(INSTALLED_APPS) + ['debug_toolbar']
```

and here is my project structure:

```
(empire243)drcongo@congodevpro:~/EmpireProjects$ tree
.
└── empireMarket // dJANGO GENERATED PROJECT BY DJANGO-ADMIN.PY STARTPROJECT
    ├── manage.py
    └── src
        ├── empireMarket
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── settings.py
        │   ├── urls.py
        │   └── wsgi.py
        └── empireWeb
            ├── admin.py
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── migrations
            │   └── __init__.py
            ├── models.py
            ├── tests.py
            └── views.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'empireWeb',
)
```

instances directory:

```
(empire243)drcongo@congodevpro:~/empireInstances$ tree
.
└── empireApp
    ├── dev_settings.py
    └── __pycache__
        └── dev_settings.cpython-34.pyc

2 directories, 2 files

settings.py

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'empireWeb',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'empireMarket.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'empireMarket.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }
#

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/
```

'

Everything sees normal but I'm still receiving an import error. Any help will be really useful. And I'm using python3

Comment: Is there actually a directory "empireMarket"? Please show the structure of your project.

Comment: Please edit your question and put that tree, properly formatted, there.

Comment: Show your INSTALLED_APPS section.

Comment: That tree structure doesn't appear to have anything to do with the code you're running. It doesn't show any of empireInstances, empireApp, or dev_settings.py.

Comment: The empireApp is the instance directory of the empireMarket and contains my dev_settings. The empireinstances, contains all my different projects instances directories

Comment: I don't understand what an "instance directory" is. Without seeing your *full* structure, there's no way we can help you.

Comment: Ok what I'm doing is having a dev_settings separated from the actual project settings. So you an find in the question bellow my dev_settings and my project_settings content.

Comment: I find it a good practice, since each person can have his own dev_settings file with different contents, and doesn't have to depend on the other settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the project is not installed into the virtualenv.

The usual way to do this is to define a `setup.py` for your package, which should go into the root of your package (usually the directory that contains `src`). A minimal one might look something like this:

**empireMarket/setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='empireMarket',
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    include_package_data=True,

    install_requires=[
        'Django',
    ]
),
```

Once you have that, you can use either `pip install <dir>` or `pip install -e <dir>` to install your package into the virtualenv.

Once that is done, importing `empireMarket.settings` should work.

Comment: Thanks very much Piet, sorted